# How to pass an Array to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
Array (
  0 => 
  Person::array (
      'name' => 'Paulo',
      'age' => 15,
    )


app.controller('myCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
 $http.get('ajax/getPerson.php').success(function(data){
 $scope.list = data;

...
```

I do not want the data to be visible in getPessoa.php. There is some other way to move my data (array) for AngularJS so that it is hidden?

**UPDATE:**

```
$myArray;

<div ng-app="">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="myArray in names">
      {{ names.x }}
      {{ names.y }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There are numerous security measures you can implement but unfortunately the question is far too broad for a simple answer here. Also, any data sent to browser is always viewable using browser dev tools

Comment: Of course, but I'm using framework and I want to pass data without  $http.get('ajax/getPerson.php'). Do you know other methods to pass data to AngularJS?

Comment: depends on use case...nothing that prevents viewing it though

Comment: For exemplo, imagine that I have an array with some datas and I want to pass this array to AngularJS without $http.get. I will update the question.

Comment: Take a look in my example... This is what I want to do....

Comment: Instead of requesting the data through `$http` you could produce a dynamically generated js-file including an angular services definition, which you could then inject into your controller. Though without good reason, this approach could be too complicated.

Comment: Yep... I'm trying to do this datagrid:
http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: but, that's complicated to do in php Smarty Framework